# Finding the date for a given week number

Tags: ruby, date

I am trying to do some date math based on the week number of a given year. For example:

```
date = Date.today # Monday, March 5, 2012
puts date.cwyear  # 2012
puts date.cweek   # 10 (10th week of 2012)
```

Now that I know what the current week is, I want to figure out what the next week and previous week are. I need to take the year (2012) and the week number (10) and turn it back into a date object so I can calculate the value for the next/previous week. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this in Rails/can you use ActiveSupport? It provides some nice date helpers for things like this. Also, by "next and previous week" do you mean exactly seven days after and prior to the `date` or the start of those weeks?

Comment: this is a Sinatra application, but if ActiveSupport provides the features to be able to do this, and I can use it with a Sinatra application, I would be willing to use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want [`Date.commercial`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial):

```
require 'date'
now = Date.today                                           #=> 2012-03-05
monday_next_week = Date.commercial(now.cwyear,now.cweek+1) #=> 2012-03-12
next_sunday_or_today = monday_next_week - 1                #=> 2012-03-11
```

Note that weeks start on Monday, so if you are on a Sunday and ask for next monday - 1 you'll get the same day.

Note also that if you don't want Mondays you can also specify the day number in the method:

```
thursday_next_week = Date.commercial(now.cwyear,now.cweek+1,4) #=> 2012-03-15
```

Comment: @Ansar What did you do then?

Comment: @PratikBothra look at my answer to get proper week number

Answer (score 3):

Calculating on a day basis is pretty simple with `Date` objects. If you just want to get the previous / next week from a given `Date` object use the following:

```
date = Date.today
previous_week = (date - 7).cweek
next_week = (date + 7).cweek
```

Comment: That looks promising. Now, how would I initialize a new date object from a given week and year (i.e. not this week)?

Comment: @steenslag It's just something you often get used to having (especially if most of your Ruby (Date) work happens to be with Rails). Not too different than being used to having `inject` in Ruby and then going to Java and you have to write it all yourself—it's just another common library. I'm all for using Ruby core before a dependency, but if you already have ActiveSupport there why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

In ActiveSupport you have helper to convert `Fixnum` to time http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html use:

```
date = Date.today
week_ago = date - 1.week
next_week = date + 1.week
```

Comment: That looks promising. Now, how would I initialize a new date object from a given week and year (i.e. not this week)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "a given week number in the current year", you can do the following:

```
2.weeks.since(Time.gm(Time.now.year))
=> Fri Jan 15 00:00:00 UTC 2010
```

Substitute (week_number - 1) for the 1 in the above, and you'll get a date in the desired week.

Answer (score 0):

I have created some methods to get week number of a given date
something like this:

```
def self.get_week(date)
    year = date.year
    first_monday_of_the_year = self.get_first_monday_of_the_year(year)
    # The first days of January may belong to the previous year!
    if date < first_monday_of_the_year
      year -= 1
      first_monday_of_the_year = self.get_first_monday_of_the_year(year)
    end
    day_difference = date - first_monday_of_the_year
    week = (day_difference / 7).to_i + 1
    week
  end

   def self.get_monday_of_year_week(year, week)
    d = self.get_first_monday_of_the_year(year)
    d + ((week - 1) * 7).days
  end

  def self.get_first_monday_of_the_year(year)
    d = Date.new(year, 1, 7)  # 7 Jan is always in the first week
    self.get_monday_of_week(d)
  end

  def self.get_monday_of_week(date)
    wday = (date.wday + 6) % 7
    date - wday.days
  end
```